# WHILE LOOP counting

Tags: java, while-loop

In java how do I tell a while loop to run as long as an input device is sending back lower values

```
double leftDist = distanceSensorLeft.getDistance(DistanceUnit.MM);
double rightDist = distanceSensorRight.getDistance(DistanceUnit.MM);
leftDrive.setTargetPosition(leftDrive.getCurrentPosition() - 1500);
rightDrive.setTargetPosition(rightDrive.getCurrentPosition() + 1500);
leftDrive.setPower(0.2);
rightDrive.setPower(-0.2);
while (leftDrive.isBusy() && rightDrive.isBusy() && opModeIsActive() && rightDist/* value is smaller than previous value*/  && leftDist// value is smaller than previous value  ) {

}
```

Comment: Please remove comments from the code and explain them in the text instead and also try to clarify what your problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the last Value in a variable and then compare it with the actual one.

```
 boolean continueBool= true;
 double lastValue=0;
 double leftDist = distanceSensorLeft.getDistance(DistanceUnit.MM);
 double rightDist = distanceSensorRight.getDistance(DistanceUnit.MM);
 leftDrive.setTargetPosition(leftDrive.getCurrentPosition() - 1500);
 rightDrive.setTargetPosition(rightDrive.getCurrentPosition() + 1500);
 leftDrive.setPower(0.2);
 rightDrive.setPower(-0.2);

 while (continueBool) {
        if(lastValue<=actualValue){
        continueBool=false;
    }

        lastValue=actualValue;

}
```